# Match string with vowels at the end using Regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to return items in a list that has any four or more characters in the string at the end of the item (could be repeated).

The string is = `"iaeou"`

I wrote

```
"[iaeou]+{4,}$"
```

This is not returning what I want, I'd like to know what is wrong with it.

I get error 'multiple repeat'.

```
>>> example = ['ti','tii','ta','tae','taeguu','fy']
>>> import re
>>> for item in example:
...  if re.search("[iaeou]+{4,}$",item):
...   print(item)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 183, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 286, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py", line 930, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py", line 426, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py", line 654, in _parse
    source.tell() - here + len(this))
re.error: multiple repeat at position 8
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write it like this,

```
[iaeou]{4,}$
```

This part '+{4,}' in your regex is not valid, because + itself is a quantifier and {4,} also is a quantifier and you can't quantify a quantifier for the regex to be valid, due to which you must be getting some pattern error. In case you literally want to quantify a + sign, you will need to escape that like this,

```
\+{1,4}
```

but that is not what you wanted as per your question. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask why + is causing the error?

Comment: + means one or more which is just like saying {1,} You were having two quantifiers + as well as {4,} which is not valid. You can only have one quantifier like Either you could write [iaeou]+$ or [iaeou]{4,}$ but not [iaeou]+{4,}$ as this becomes invalid. + is a special character in regex which means 1 or more so you can't quantify + character as it is. You can escape it and then quantify but I don't think you wanted that

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi You should include that explanation in your answer.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn: Sorry, you're right I should have added the explanation. Done now. Thanks for pointing out.